# How do you position a menu to start at the end of its parent with transition?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu inside a link positioned to the bottom of this link with `position: absolute`. I use `translateY` rule because link have diferent height on diferent screens, but I use an animation and it override the `translateY` rule while transitions happens.

```css
nav {
  text-align: right
}

.dropdown,
.trigger,
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.trigger {
  background: yellow
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  height: 50px; /* The height is variable*/
  position: absolute;
}

.trigger:focus + .menu{
   opacity: 1;
   animation: toogle-show-menu 0.25s;
}

@keyframes toogle-show-menu {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="trigger">
      LINK MENU
    </button>

    <div class="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Otherwise, I would like to know if there is another html structure to handle this easier.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for

Comment: im not get what you mean, can you put 1 image of result that you want and 1 image of result that you currently achieve

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: I'd just like to add that you can have several functions in the transform property when animating it. So you can go from `transform: scale(0.95) translateY(100%);` to `transform: scale(1) translateY(100%);` which will keep your initial `transform: translateY(100%)` all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `top:100%`

```css
nav {
  text-align: right
}

.dropdown,
.trigger,
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.trigger {
  background: yellow
}

.menu {
  background: orange;
  top:100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px; /* The height is variable*/
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="trigger">
      LINK MENU
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```